# AntiAlias failed when draw string with certain angle in GDI+

Tags: c++, string, gdi+, antialiasing

I am using the following code to draw Strings. In GDI+

```
Graphics tempFontGr(XXX);
Matrix* myPathMatrix = NULL;
 myPathMatrix->Rotate(GetDCAngle(), MatrixOrderPrepend);
cantempFontGr.SetTransform(myPathMatrix);
tempFontGr.SetInterpolationMode(InterpolationModeHighQuality);
tempFontGr.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeAntiAlias);
tempFontGr.DrawString(m_sWords, -1, tempFont.get(), tempRec, NULL, m_pBrush.get());
```

It is anoying that the string drawn have alias. Is there any method to remove the alias?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetSmoothingMode` applies to lines and curves. Try [`SetTextRenderingHint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535817(VS.85).aspx)